# MotoX 2014 has 24GB out of 32GB available

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, motorola-moto-g

Keeping in mind that the same OS (Lolipop) runs on MotoG which can be 8 GB, how can it be that OS takes up 8 GB? MotoX comes with only a couple of extra software, which surely cannot much space…

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this was my device, I'd perform a Factory Reset to see what the storage looks like after that.

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).

Comment: I have added the screenshots

Comment: So this would make sense if there are 3GB for system hidden from these apps

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a factory reset. If your memory is still such 'low' comparing it to the other models then it's just the way it is. Flashing the entire stock image may be a good thing to do since it may be firmware related.

Answer (score 0):

I have Moto X 2014. Stock ROM. The storage you get is 24.98gb. Even if you factory reset it. You will still have the same.